# Object reference tracking in runtime

Tags: c#, .net, clr, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm curious about whether it's possible to track operations under object references in runtime (copying, accessing etc.).
For example, if I debug the following code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
   // Creating new object and reference.
   var myList = new List<int>();
   // a) Copying a reference to method.
   UpdateList(myList);
}              

private static void UpdateList(IList<int> list)
{
    // b) Copying the reference.
    var localList = list;

    // c) Accessing the object through copied reference.
    localList.Add(1);
    // d) Copying a reference to method.
    int count = GetListElementsCount(localList);
}

private static int GetListElementsCount(IList<int> list)
{
     // Another reference access.
     // Breakpoint here.
     return list.Count;
}
```

and put a breakpoint into `GetListElementsCount`, can I look through the `list` argument origin and changes made to it (a, b, c, d)?
Does Roslyn compiler provide some C# API for this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/DataFlowAnalysis.cs

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature called [Historical Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228143.aspx) in Visual Studio Enterprise.  With some [limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx#Anchor_3) (collects variables in `Autos` and `Local` windows only) it provides possibility to look on variable history without actual code re-execution.

Answer (score 0):

It very depend in your specific needs.

You can check the [DataFlowAnalysis](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/DataFlowAnalysis.cs) as [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) comment, if it fit your needs.

Or of course you can use the simple naive option, use logging before\after each relevant operation.

If those two options are not enough, you can try do it with instrumentation by wrapping every creation\get\set etc.

Instrumentation can be static like [StaticProxy.Fody](https://github.com/BrunoJuchli/StaticProxy.Fody) or dynamic (Castle, LinFu, Sprint.Net etc.).

Other type of instrumentation is [Instant](https://github.com/ermau/Instant) project. It use NRefactory but you can easily convert it to use Roslyn.

After you have information about your runtime behaviour you can use it as you want.

In your example, after you saved all object changes in some data structure and break in `GetListElementsCount` method, you can investigate your data structure and ask for a specific operation.

Your data structure can be (just for very simple example):
Dictionary where key is the operation name and value is the new value after the operation is run.

For creation: key = "creation", value = List

For call list.Add(1): key = method call - Add, value = 1